# JENKINS Error cloning remote repo 'origin' Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"

Tags: java, git, selenium, jenkins, gitlab

I am trying to run Selenium test cases onto Jenkins from a GitLab repo. I made it work on a RHEL VM and am attempting to construct this on Windows. However I am unable to get the builds to be successful. Jenkins apparently fails to get the repo from GitLab in the first place and I am left with a console output like this:

```
13:13:13 Cloning the remote Git repository
13:13:13 Cloning repository https://gitlab.user.com/user/testing.git
13:13:13  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init C:\jenkins\workspace\Testing # timeout=10
13:13:13 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
13:13:13 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init C:\jenkins\workspace\Testing
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1048)
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:803)
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:160)
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
13:13:13    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
13:13:13    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
13:13:13    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
13:13:13    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
13:13:13    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
13:13:13    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
13:13:13    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
13:13:13    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:122)
13:13:13    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
13:13:13    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 10.172.0.74/10.172.0.74:57192
13:13:13        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1795)
13:13:13        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
13:13:13        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
13:13:13        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
13:13:13        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2125.invoke(Unknown Source)
13:13:13        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
13:13:13        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
13:13:13        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:131)
13:13:13        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.execute(Unknown Source)
13:13:13        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1224)
13:13:13        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1302)
13:13:13        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
13:13:13        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1213)
13:13:13        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:637)
13:13:13        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
13:13:13        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:509)
13:13:13        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
13:13:13        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
13:13:13        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
13:13:13        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
13:13:13 Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init C:\jenkins\workspace\Testing
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2689)
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2611)
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2607)
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1974)
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1046)
13:13:13    ... 12 more
13:13:13 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" (in directory "C:\jenkins\workspace\Testing"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
13:13:13    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
13:13:13    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
13:13:13    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
13:13:13    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
13:13:13    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:995)
13:13:13    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:507)
13:13:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2674)
13:13:13    ... 16 more
13:13:13 Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
13:13:13    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
13:13:13    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:487)
13:13:13    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:154)
13:13:13    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
13:13:13    ... 22 more
13:13:13 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
13:13:13 Finished: FAILURE
```

On following advice from similar posts on this site, I had set the Jenkins Shell path to the git.exe on my Windows machine. But I am unable to get past this error. Can someone point me in the right direction to fix this? Let me know if any further information is required, and thanks for reading.

Comment: Try on a command prompt: cd  "C:\jenkins\workspace\Testing" and then "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe". If it works, it can be due to the space in directory "Program Files". In this case install git in another directory with no spaces.

Comment: Hey @pringi the first command won't work since Jenkins is installed on a server rather than my local machine. Am I supposed to change something related to that?

Comment: Do you have Git Plugin installed? If not try it. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_git_setup.htm. If the problem persists, create a simple job that uses command line and execute the  cd "C:\jenkins\workspace\Testing" and then "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" to see if it works.